# How to Query using Or Condition in DBCursor

Tags: mongodb

I have my MongoDB structure as shown below:

```
  {
    "_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "_class" : "com.cts.adpart.domain.DBData",
    "file" : "xyz",
    "owner" : "user1",
    "curList" : [
             {                     
                    "approver" : "user2",
                    "reviewer" : "user3",
                    "country" : "India"
             },
    "curFlag" : true
  },
  {
    "_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "_class" : "com.cts.adpart.domain.DBData",
    "file" : "xyz",
    "owner" : "user2"
    "curList" : [
             {
                    "approver" : "user1",
                    "reviewer" : "user3",
                    "country" : "India"
             },
    "curFlag" : true
  }
```

Owner name will be the user name.

I have to implement search in such a way that if 
1. curFlag is True, 
2. Country is India 
3. if the username is listed in some document as reviewer or approver then that result also should come in search

I have tried in the following way:

```
        DBCollection myColl = mongoTemplate.getCollection("User_Collection");
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("curFlag", true);
        query.append("country","India")
        DBObject approver = new BasicDBObject("curList.reviewer", Util.getOwner());  
        DBObject reviewer = new BasicDBObject("curList.approver", Util.getOwner());    
        BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
        or.add(approver);
        or.add(reviewer);
        query.append("$or", or);
```

I am not getting the exact result here.

The above query works like if country is India and curFlag is true and owner name is listed as approver or reviewer it is listing that document.

But I want to query like if country is India and curFlag is true or owner name is listed as approver or reviewer i should list that document.

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: please correct your json document structure its not in correct format ,and  exaplain whats your expected output,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If youre trying like this,

```
    db.User_Collection.find({
        $or: [{
            "curList.country": "India",
            "curFlag": true
        }, {
            $or: [{
                "curList.approver": "user1"
            }, {
                "curList.reviewer": "user1"
            }]
        }]
    }).pretty()
```

Then your java code should be,

```
        DBCollection myColl = mongoTemplate.getCollection("User_Collection");
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("curFlag", true);
        query.append("country","India")
        DBObject approver = new BasicDBObject("curList.reviewer", Util.getOwner());  
        DBObject reviewer = new BasicDBObject("curList.approver", Util.getOwner());    
        BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
        or.add(approver);
        or.add(reviewer);
        query.append("$or", or);

        BasicDBList orQueryList = new BasicDBList();
        orQueryList.add(query);
        orQueryList.add(or);
        BasicDBObject fullQuery = new BasicDBObject("$or", orQueryList);
```

Use fullQuery object to query data from collection.